# make a view to allow single touch

Tags: iphone

How to make a view to allow single touch only and doesn't allow multiple touches.

I have 5 buttons in the view in order to allow multiple pressing of buttons I tried to disabling the when a button is pressed but the view doesn't allows further touches that mean the view is disabled and not enabled after the release of the button.

Comment: did u try `yourView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;`

Comment: Be specific on your requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable multitouch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080043/how-to-disable-multitouch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this previous SO question [How to disable multitouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080043/how-to-disable-multitouch) helps