# iPhone: MultiTouching

Tags: iphone

I have a lot of buttons on my view. And when I hold my finger at one of them, I still can tup on others buttons and they will do their actions. How to block that ? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u try setting the `exclusiveTouch` property to `YES`?

> exclusiveTouch
>
> A Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver handles touch
>   events exclusively.
>
> @property(nonatomic, getter=isExclusiveTouch) BOOL exclusiveTouch
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Setting this property to YES causes the receiver to block the delivery
>   of touch events to other views in the same window. The default value
>   of this property is NO.
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: U need to set that for all buttons.

Comment: self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    self.view.exclusiveTouch = YES;

Comment: Try setting it on your view in which the buttons are placed. also make sure that the `multipleTouchEnabled` is set as `YES`

Comment: self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
 self.view.exclusiveTouch = YES; But still I can tup on two buttons...What is the problem ?

Comment: Pls see this previous SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080043/how-to-disable-multitouch

Comment: Check @Mark's answer in that.

Comment: still exclusiveTouch for some reason is not working for me, I set that for all buttons ((. In any way, thanks for help...