# SpriteKit prevent more than one touch at a time

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I am making a SpriteKit game I was wondering if there was a way to prevent more than one touch at a time.

in my game an object gets added at every touch and I kinda don't want that. (even though its hilarious) if there is a way how do I do it? what would I use? and could you point me in the right direction? and I know that there are ways to do it as I have seen multiple games with that feature.

would I put something into 'appdelegate.swift' to prevent that or would it have something to do with the 'touches began' function I have tried several methods but none seem to work also I have searched all over google but to no avail.

if somebody could help me with this I would appreciate it but its not really that important as it doesn't upset the balance of the game at all.

Comment: See this link if it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080043/how-to-disable-multitouch

Comment: thanks man this helps me a lot 

Answer (score 2):

You can use [multipleTouchEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622519-multipletouchenabled) property of a `UIView`:

> When set to YES, the view receives all touches associated with a
>   multi-touch sequence and starting within the view's bounds. When set
>   to NO, the view receives only the first touch event in a multi-touch
>   sequence that start within the view's bounds. The default value of
>   this property is NO.

Use it like this `self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = false`, where self is a scene.