# How to disable multi touch on entire app or just a view using SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I wanna disable multi touch in swiftUI but I don't find any solution Is there any way to do this???

everything I found are related to UIKit :

[How to disable multitouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080043/how-to-disable-multitouch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No SwiftUI solution but you can use UIKit solution in SwiftUI app.

Use `UIView.appearance()`. This will disable multi-touch on the whole app.

```
@main
struct SwiftUIDEMO: App {
    init() {
        UIView.appearance().isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
        UIView.appearance().isExclusiveTouch = true
    }
    
    // Body View
}
```

Or you can also use `UIViewController` touch event and maange `.isUserInteractionEnabled`.

```
extension UIViewController {
    open override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    open override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    open override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: If you’re using first code init then you can write this init code to your SwiftUI view and for second approach just make a one file and place the code

Comment: Your solution is wright tnx but I understand my problem is something else I should disable multi drag gesture not touch

Comment: This not worked for me. Don't know why. SwiftUI

Comment: this work for me thanks