# SwiftUI Button/onTapGesture Dropping Inputs with error message

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I made a game using SwiftUI with normal `Button`'s. I have discovered that my buttons regularly drop inputs, which negatively affects gameplay. I am in the exact situation shown in this link:

[Tapping Button Too Quickly causes "Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67846038/tapping-button-too-quickly-causes-failed-to-receive-system-gesture-state-notifi)

As you can see in the comments of this unsolved problem, using touchesBegan with UIKit seems to be the way to get faster, more responsive buttons.

Is there something else I can do using SwiftUI to fix this issue?

I've tried disabling multitouch but to no avail

---

```
struct testView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Press me!")
        .onTapGesture{//do nothing}
    }
}
```

If I run this view on an iOS device and press this button fast enough, I get the error: "Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch"

I am running XCode 14.0 beta and running this button on an iPhone 11

---

hacky trick which maybe made button presses slightly faster but did not fix error message

```
@State var pressed = false


Text("Press Me")
.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
    .onChanged { _ in
        if !pressed {
            // mything
            pressed = true
        }
    }
    .onEnded { _ in pressed = false }
)
```

Comment: Added comment to linked post

Comment: How do you expect us to help without any provided code? that post is a year ago.

Comment: The code that is causing the issue hasn't changed from the previous post, but I added it for you anyways